# broken SQL 2008 SP1 Web Edition (can not login with SSMS)

Tags: sql-server

Scenario:

My installation of SQL Server 2008 Web Edition SP1 was working properly.

Since I've recently joined Microsoft's Website [Spark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/default.aspx), I removed SQL2008 and installed SQL 2008 again using my Website Spark edition and license from the MSDN download site.

Next, I updated SQL 2008 to SP1 (this is required because I'm running Windows 2008 Server R2 Web edition).

When I launch SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), "User name" is "myhost\Administrator" and is greyed out so it can not be changed.

When I installed my Website Spark version, I did not include "myhost\Administrator" when I was configuring SQL 2008 service accounts.

Instead I created an administrator account "myhost\mySQLaccount".

ERROR   MESSAGE:

```
Connect to Server
  (X)  Cannot connect to    (local)

   Additional information:
      Login failed for user 'myhost'Admistrator'
      (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:  18456)
```

I tried to use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to correct this problem but could not find any useful way to fix this issue.

How to I fix this problem?

```
Connect to Server ...
  Server type:          Database Engine
  Server name:           (local)
  Authentication:     Windows Authentication
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this way:

1. logged off
2. logged on using SQL Server 2008 Admin account
3. running ssms as sysadmin, added a new account
   for myhost\Administrator with sysadmin privileges.
4. logged off
5. logged back in as myhost\Administrator.
6. success, Admin account is now okay for ssms 2008

Answer (score 0):

The username is grayed out when the mode of authentication is "Windows Authentication" in the login window.

**Change the Authentication mode** to *"SQL Server Authentication"* and you should be able to edit the login name to "myhost\mySQLaccount".

Comment: thank you Raj ... I did not at this time want to use SQL Server Authenication.  See my comment to drohan.